# Users deleted with whenChanged attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, extract

I'm trying to export all users deleted in the last year.
With the query below I can export the users deleted but I need  to have also the whenChanged attribute in the results:

**Query**

```
[datetime]$StartTime = "1/1/2018"
[datetime]$EndTime = "1/1/2019"
$Filter = {Deleted -eq $true -and ObjectClass -eq "user"}
$GetDeleted = Get-ADObject -Filter {(isdeleted -eq $true) -and (name - 
ne "Deleted Objects")} -includeDeletedObjects - 
property whenChanged,LastKnownParent | 
Where-Object {$_.whenChanged -ge $StartTime -and $_.whenChanged -le 
$EndTime} | sort whenChanged | ft Name,LastKnownParent,whenChanged

Get-ADObject -filter $Filter -IncludeDeletedObjects
```

**Results:**

```
Deleted           : True
DistinguishedName : CN=XXX XXX\0ADEL:0c8597e4-95634a4e87a10af034d6a5b3,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=XXX,DC=XXX
Name              : XXX XXX
                   DEL:0c8597e4-9563-4a4e-87a1-0af034d6a5b3
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 0c8597e4-9563-4a4e-87a1-0af034d6a5b3
```

Can you help me please?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The default tombstone and object recycle lifetimes are either 60 or 180 days, so unless you've changed chose, _no object deleted more than a year ago will exist_

Comment: The code is broken because you insert newlines at arbitrary places. Also, by appending `| ft Name,LastKnownParent,whenChanged` you are just outputting stuff on screen and variable `$GetDeleted` will contain nothing.